# Sqlite EF6 primary key type mismatch

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6

We wanted to move our db related tests from postgres to sqlite, so we've installed sqlite, converted DDL scripts so they fit the syntax of sqlite and ran the tests. And here it goes:

> The type of the key field 'Id' is expected to be 'System.Int32', but
>   the value provided is actually of type 'System.Int64'.

on the line
`//roleId is int as well as p.Id`
`var role = RoleItems.Single(p => p.Id == roleId);`

---

Id is a primary key in db (sqlite integer)
Id property is .NET integer

Is there any way this situation can be resolved without the need to change Id properties to .NET long? Any help appriciated.

Comment: AFAIR, there is no way to change type of fetched data.

Comment: I think if you changed the data type in your database (not to mention changing the entire database platform) you'd better update your accompanying EF model (do you use EDMX?). If the DB is returning a 64-bit number than C# needs to be able to handle that. The error is telling you that what you're trying to do is unreliable - in theory eventually your DB ID values can go beyond the values which a 32-bit int can store, so it wouldn't be able to work with them.

Comment: If you were retrieving a 32-bit int into a 64-bit field you might get away with it, but you can't expect to cram a bigger field into a smaller field, it just doesn't work - you lose vital information in the process, and the code cannot know what to do with that situation.

Comment: @ADyson, it's code-first, no EDMX. Em, the core problem is sqlite integer primary key column. I was digging the sqlite documentation to solve this one, but i found no way to switch the behavior - rowid column type is int64 and primary key is always rowid if not stated WITHOUT ROWID, but this option disables the opprtunity for key to autoincrement. So, i thought maybe there is some kind of a trick to make things work.

Comment: No. 64-bit into 32-bit will never go. You have to change your C# code to match.